# Finding SQL Server name with the help of Data Source Name in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a login window, where I have to provide ODBC Name, database name, user id and password. Whereas for connection string I need SQL Server name. Is there any way I can find respective SQL Server name with the help of ODBC Name? I am new to C# programming and have no idea even if it is possible or not.

[image]

[image]

Comment: All ODBC settings are stored in the registry :)

Comment: does this really have to be dynamic? if you know up front, make your connection string to have the server name once you find out. Check out https://www.connectionstrings.com/ for a pretty complete list of all the connection strings youll ever need.

Comment: if you have an ODBC DSN, you should use an `OdbcConnection` and then you don't need the server name. It's quite illogical to use the ODBC DSN data to extract an SQL Server name that you can then use for an ADO.NET connection -- that sort of thing is more properly done by storing the connection string in the application's `.config`.

Comment: DSN names I have have spaces with them and it's causing connection fail.

Answer (score 1):

Basically system stores the DSN information here HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI

This code basically reads this info from registry

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string DSN = "TEST";
    using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey localMachineHive = Registry.LocalMachine)
    using (RegistryKey odbcDriversKey = localMachineHive.OpenSubKey(string.Format(@"SOFTWARE\ODBC\odbc.ini\{0}", DSN)))
    {
        if (odbcDriversKey != null)
        {
            Console.Write(odbcDriversKey.GetValue("Server").ToString());
        }
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

if you need more info about the DSN the code below give you a list of the subkey names you may need.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string DSN = "TEST";
        string[] subKeyNames = null;
        using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey localMachineHive = Registry.LocalMachine)
        using (RegistryKey odbcDriversKey = localMachineHive.OpenSubKey(string.Format(@"SOFTWARE\ODBC\odbc.ini\{0}", DSN)))
        {
            subKeyNames = odbcDriversKey.GetValueNames();
            foreach (var subKey in subKeyNames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(subKey.ToString());
            }

        }
        Console.Read();
    }

//Result will be 

//Driver
//Server
//LastUser
//...
//..
//.
```